# Last day today, submit resignation tomorrow without notice-period

Tags: resignation, notice-period

I'm new to my job, about less than a week, but I already want to resign because of personal reasons, I want today to be my last day in my job. Can I give my resignation letter tomorrow? Will there be a problem?
And what if I can't provide the 30-day notice that's written on my contract?

my contract is 6 months and i'm from philippines.
I graduated last may 2017

Comment: That depends on your contract and laws of your location.

Comment: You need to give wayyy more information. What industry, how did you get the job, how fresh are you out of college, what does your contract say etc. In the United States you can quit any time although you'll lose a huge amount of credibility among your co-workers and in that organization.

Comment: This depends on location as @skymningen points out.

Comment: If you do, definitely don't include this on your resume or ask for references.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings sorry, my first time posting here.

Comment: @Athena - NP at all.  Does that question help answer your question?  If not why not?

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings the question in the link you've given me is somehow different coz in my case, I really can't provide or serve the 30-day notice for some reasons. And I can't give X days notice too.

Comment: What is the general reason why you cant... IE if you have something medical going on just medical is enough.  If its just that you dont want too... that is alot different than if you have something going on that prevents you from being able to.  And if it is just that you do not want to then the duplicate would be appropriate.  If there is something preventing you from being able to complete your notice, then in order to help you better we need more than just personal.  Even if it is just something "personal that I can not avoid and do not want to disclose"

Comment: You have been to this job for less than a week. Is there any reason you cannot just stop going to work tomorrow and pretend that this job never existed? They will probably not pay for those days, but I guess you wouldn't mind that, would you?

Comment: @MaskedMan-仮面の男 I wouldn't mind.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings it's really far away from home that i need to spend almost 6 hours back and forth. And there's this unexpected thing that happen that i need to be away from my hometown for about 3 months, family reasons.

Answer (score 5):

> I want today to be my last day in my job. Can I give my resignation letter tomorrow? [Ed: without notice]

You CAN.  I wouldn't recommend it, though.

> Will there be a problem? And what if I can't provide the 30-day notice?

Depending on your location and local laws, you might get sued for breach of contract.  Even if the company doesn't care enough to follow through on that, it will obviously impact your future efforts to find a new job.  Nobody wants to hire a guy who doesn't respect the terms of his contracts and might suddenly quit without giving notice.

If you *really want/need* to leave but cannot give the full 30 days notice as required by the contract, then you should at least *give as much notice as possible.*  Speak to your manager, explain that you want to quit but can only give X days notice.  There's a good chance they'll accept it, even if they aren't happy about it, because you're being honest and upfront about the situation.

Also, if you've only been there a week, you may still be within the probationary period (again, depending on your location) and therefore not actually be required to give the full 30 days notice.  Again, check your contract for probationary periods and speak with your manager.

Whatever you do, **don't** try to pull a fast one and just walk out without explaining yourself or trying to talk with people.  That's only going to piss them off and ruin your own reputation in the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resign, you resign. If you are supposed to give 30 days notice, and for some reason you can't, and the employer insists, then you have a problem.

On the other hand, no reasonable employer would want you there if you quit after 7 days. So I would strongly suggest that you talk to someone with authority *in person*, and see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

You typically can, and often do so without issues.

As previous commenters have mentioned, issues arising from leaving your role without the formalities however, does depend on the contract that you would have signed. It's not unusual for contracts to include a period of time that you maybe on probation and have a leave clause which is a lot more relaxed than if you were not on an initial probation.

Have a read of your contract thoroughly, especially if you are worried about any repercussions.

The company that hired you will almost always want the employee to be happy. And will make allowances for employees to leave roles early if it really doesn't work out. Raising this with your direct manager should be the next step.

Leaving roles after very brief periods is generally frowned upon by future employers however. As long as this is not a continual occurrence, leaving brief stints out of your CV should have no real consequence on your future career.

Comment: On the other hand, leaving after a week is probably better for the employer than leaving after a month.